# Как вывести результат функции в main?

Tags: c, строки, main

Есть код, который выводит строки в обратном порядке :

```
int zerkalo (char *s){
        int len = strlen(s)-1;
     printf("вы ввели: ");
char*t = s + len;
for (;t>=s;t--) printf("%c",*t);
return 0;
}

 int main () {
     setlocale(0,"");
     char vvod [50]={};
     printf("Введите слово (слова, предложение)\n");
     scanf("%50[^\n]s",vvod);
 zerkalo(vvod);
   printf("\n");
      return 0;
 }
```

Вопрос в следующем: как вывести уже измененный массив `vvod`, не с помощью `printf("%c",*t)` в функции `zerkalo`, а в самой функции `main`?

Ведь в функции `zerkalo`  я работаю с указателями, значит после отработки данной функции, `vvod` в `main` должен по идее имеет измененное значение. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Просто работайте с `char *s` внутри функции через индексы (как с массивом). Если вы поменяете значение в массиве внутри функции, то изменения будут видны и снаружи. Вспомните алгоритм разворота массива

Answer (score 2):

Каждая функция должна заниматься своим делом. Одна разворачивает строку, другая выводит...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverse(char* s)
{
    if (s == NULL) return s;
    for(char *b = s, *e = s + strlen(s) - 1;
        b < e; ++b, --e)
    {
        char t = *b; *b = *e; *e = t;
    }
    return s;
}
int main ()
{
    char vvod[50];
    printf("Введите слово (слова, предложение): ");
    scanf("%50[^\n]s",vvod);
    printf("%s\n", reverse(vvod));
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, зачем *b = s, если  s и есть *s? И для чего оператор * в имени функции?  char t = *b; *b = *e; *e = t; - здесь идет замена ячеек массива ( первый с последним и т.к.)?

Comment: 1. Чтоб вернуть указатель на переданную строку. 2. Потому что работаем с указателями. 3. Да.

Comment: 1. если использовать сразу *s без объявления нового указателя *b? ( t = *s; *s = *e; *e = t;) это будет считаться ошибкой? (пробовал так тоже работает, и без * в имени функции, работает правильно)

Comment: Работать будет, но что вы при этом будете возвращать? Вы потеряете переданный адрес. Можно, конечно, и без него, но тогда `printf("%s\n", reverse(vvod));` не получится. В моем примере идет посимвольный обмен ячеек. Нарисуйте полоску клеточек - строку, куда указывают b, e и пройдите пошагово, что получается.